# The deriviative of $\sqrt{\ln(x)}$, by definition

Tags: functions

How do I find the deriviative of $\sqrt{\ln(x)}$, by definition? I got stuck thinking of a solution... Would be glad of getting help/hints.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean *by definition*? Also, the expression is not defined for $x \in (0, 1)$.

Comment: By definition: $$f'(x)=\lim_{x->x_0}{f(x)-f(x_0)\over x-x_0}$$

Comment: I thought so. When I first learnt calculus, calculating this limit was referred to as finding the derivative *by first principles*.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For $x\in (1,+\infty)$,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sqrt{\ln(x+h)}-\sqrt{\ln x}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+h)-\ln x}{h}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(x+h)}+\sqrt{\ln x}}=\\
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\ln(x+h)}+\sqrt{\ln x}}\cdot
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+h)-\ln x}{h}=\\\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\ln(x)}}\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+h)-\ln x}{h}$$
The last limit is the derivative of $\ln x$. Check differentiability at $x=1$ separately.

Comment: Ah... the alternative definition. Thanks! But I don't understand how you went from the second phase to the third...

Comment: @pie You can easily do the same with the "standard" definition as well. I used the continuity of $\ln$

Comment: But I don't understand how you went from the second phase to the third. I guess it's the same idea in the other definition.

Comment: @pie I believe my edit explains it better

Comment: Oh I see, thanks!